# Не удается получить значения

Tags: ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Код:

```
var data = $('#myArea2').val()
$.post("SendData.php", { data: data} );
```

Не передается переменная data. Почему это может быть? 
Если вместо второй data написать "любой текст", то всё будет ок. И что еще интересно, если вывести alert(data) - всё работает, значения выведены (но не переданы в post).

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = $('#myArea2').val();//прежде чем передавать значение убедитесь, чтооно не пустое. И точку с запятой забыли поставить.
$.post("SendData.php", { data: data},function(data){} );
```

**P.S.** попробуйте получить переменную data через `$_REQUEST['data']`